# ffmpeg hardware decode mpeg2 file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to hardware transcode input.ts file captured by over the air antenna on plex server to an output.mp4.  The file is mpeg2, should mpeg2_qsv be specified as the decoder since the original file is mpeg2 or does h264_qsv hardware decode mpeg2 files...if not has it been using software instead of hardware decoding when using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.ts -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4"
```

Comment: Use FFprobe or MediaInfo and check the video codec of `input.ts` (add the information to your post). `mpeg2` may refer to mpeg2 transport stream (container), but the video codec is the relevant information. In case all you need is converting the TS to MP4, you better use `ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v copy output.mp4` (re-encoding is not required).

Comment: With ffprobe I get : Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc                      I do want to transcode to reduce file sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codec of the input video is mpg2 (MPEG video Version 2).
The video applies interlace scan (not progressive scan).

The correct command for transcoding the video is:

```
ffmpeg -c:v mpeg2_qsv -i input.ts -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4
```

As far as I know, we don't have to use `-hwaccel qsv`, because there is nothing be accelerated in this simple transcoding (except decoding and encoding that handled by `mpeg2_qsv` and `h264_qsv`).

---

Testing:

Build synthetic input file (for testing):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=720x480:rate=59.94:duration=3 -vf "interlace=scan=tff:lowpass=complex,format=yuv420p" -c:v mpeg2video -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +ilme+ildct in.ts
```

Using FFprobe for getting information:

```
ffprobe in.ts
```

Relevant output:
`Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc`

Transcoding:

```
ffmpeg -y -c:v mpeg2_qsv -i in.ts -c:v h264_qsv out.mp4
```

I am getting the following warning messages (but the output file is "playable"):

> [h264_qsv @ 00000260ccae6980] Warning during encoding: incompatible video parameters (5)
> Last message repeated 83 times
> [mpeg2_qsv @ 00000260cca35080] A decode call did not consume any data: expect more data at input (-10)
> [h264_qsv @ 00000260ccae6980] Warning during encoding: incompatible video parameters (5)
> [mpeg2_qsv @ 00000260cca35080] A decode call did not consume any data: expect more data at input (-10)
> [h264_qsv @ 00000260ccae6980] Warning during encoding: incompatible video parameters (5)
> [mpeg2_qsv @ 00000260cca35080] A decode call did not consume any data: expect more data at input (-10)

Probing the output file:

```
ffprobe out.mp4
```

Relevant output:
`Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 789 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)`

---

Decoding mpeg2 video codec is not very CPU intensive, so in case the `mpeg2_qsv` in not working, you may use CPU decoding and hardware accelerated encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4
```

Comment: I ran some tests tonight.. getting a lot of errors : [mpeg2_qsv @ 0x55ae3e309dc0] A decode call did not consume any data: expect more data at input (-10)  This error constantly appears on the screen on each line
This error I was getting without adding the -hwaccel bit  Warnng during encoding incompatible video parameters (5)  Also get a warning about "Please explicitly set "-hwaccel_output_format qsv"   and another that "codec frame size is not set"     Any way to clear that first error?

Comment: It looks like `mpeg2_qsv` decoder is not stable. As I posted you may be forced to use software decoding (read my answer to the end). I don't know about `-hwaccel_output_format qsv`, but if it helps add it. You may also try updating the Intel HD Graphics driver, and using the latest FFmpeg version. There is also a chance that the input files are not standard. Are you getting errors or warnings?

Comment: just getting warnings, the file it creates works fine.  My test/source file is 875MB and the hardware qsv mpeg 2 to h264_qsv encoder gave me the quickest time so far of 3 min 27 seconds and a good file reduction to 417 MB which puts it in my target window.  I'm going to test some more of the hardware encoders to see how they compare.  The hevc_qsv took a long time and the result was not much smaller.  I did add the format wording to the command and that warning went away.. now the only one I get is the one that keeps repeating about decode call.. but it doesn't seem to be harming the result.